# Is there a way to convert an HTML page styled with Bootstrap CSS into email-compatible html?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-email

Is there a way to convert an HTML page styled with Bootstrap CSS into an html email compatible form?  I see that there are entirely different CSS frameworks, like [Ink](http://zurb.com/ink/), for creating email compatible HTML, but is there a flow for creating an email that doesn't require the use of a different CSS framework?  Is there a good HTML -> PDF -> email HTML flow?  Or any other flow?

Comment: You have to be very careful when making emails with HTML as email clients are horrible at rendering. Someone once said to me "make your email HTML as if it's still 1999" :)

Comment: In particular, you can't use float, which Bootstrap uses everywhere.

Comment: Yes. @DavidG is correct. You would need to use tables. I typically grab a mailchimp template or two to investigate then use that as a guide.

Comment: I discovered the limitations of bootstrap already :-D  I'm wondering if there is a flow to transform a bootstrap flow into an email compatible form.  Maybe something that re-encodes incompatible bootstrap CSS with email compatible CSS.

Comment: Keep your emails as basic as possible.   Put an IMG at the top with a logo/etc with your branded colors and such, and then content below it.

Comment: I think the only reliable way you would be able to get a Bootstrap page into a properly formatted email would be to generate a static image from the page.

Comment: DavidG, I'm experimenting with chrome/webkit->PDF and then linux's `pdftohtml -c -s` and the rendering isn't too shabby, but it still isn't email html.  I'm crossing my fingers that someone know of a working flow :-P

Comment: It's not only the CSS it's also the html. You can't use the divs, you would need to convert  the content to tables etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for a couple of reasons...

First, there is no reliable CSS or HTML with email. Clients are all over the place in terms of CSS support & how they render HTML, so this is a structural/semantic problem. It isn't about converting classes so much as completely altering the HTML structure.

As explained in [this CSS Tricks post](http://css-tricks.com/ideas-behind-responsive-emails/), a typical solution is ol-skool techniques like table-based layouts, requiring you to entirely restructure your existing HTML. You also have to add some client-specific hacks.

Second, and more importantly, you [shouldn't send *everything* on the existing page as an email](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-complete-guide-to-designing-for-email--webdesign-12941). Even if it's a newsletter for subscribers, people probably won't read it. Instead, create a short & sweet 1-column template to plop in the latest headlines & minimal info they'd most care about, with links to the articles or even a PDF version online.

Finally, many email clients won't automatically download images. If you try to send a static image of the existing page, most people won't see it by default. If that's *all* you send they'll see a blank email and immediately delete it. Best practices for accessibility also apply here - no actual text means nothing for screen readers, not to mention nothing for people who disable HTML emails in favor of plain text.

Better approach is as described above - images to a minimum with semantic text below that your recipients are sure to see. Stick to a 1-column layout to simplify making it a responsive template.

Some additional links:

http://www.lireo.com/responsive-html-email/

http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/a_responsive_design_tutorial

http://rmion.com/responsive-html-email/

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-simple-responsive-html-email--webdesign-12978